# C# Value reset between Form and DLL

Tags: c#, class

I have a program which uses two classes in a DLL and a Form for display results.

My first class:

```
public class Channels
{
 public int Wavelength = 0;
}
```

The second:

```
public class SayMyName
{
 public Channels CH1 = new Channels();
 public void Wave(string longu)
 {
  CH1.Wavelength = 01064; //breakpoint here, all is good
 }
}
```

And my Form:

```
public SayMyName pub = new SayMyName();
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string longu = textBox3.Text;
 pub.Wave(longu); //breakpoint here, my value in CH1.Wavelength is reset?!
 textBox2.Text = CH1.Wavelength.ToString();
}
```

This program display 0 in my textbox.

I put a breakpoint in my class `SayMyName` and `CH1.Wavelength`= 1064.
I put an other breakpoint in my Form and there `CH1.Wavelength`=0.

How can I keep the value in `CH1.Wavelength`?

Comment: This code will not compile. A. `long` is a preserved C# word B. you cant do `CH1.Wavelength` you can do `pub.CH1.Wavelength`

Comment: Thanks you, of course `long` was a random name not what i wrote !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this:

```
 textBox2.Text = CH1.Wavelength.ToString();
```

To this:

```
 textBox2.Text = pub.CH1.Wavelength.ToString();
```

This way you will access a CH1 variable of a pub object, not just CH1 out of nowhere.